# Log database connections hanging

Tags: java, logging, connection, sybase

I have a java application that connects to a Sybase database.

I want to log, at the application level, database connections that are hanging.

I am not sure this is possible, if so, help me on this issue.

Comment: Do you mean 'log when a database connection hangs', or 'log when a database connection times out'?

Comment: actually, it's when the database connection hangs...

Comment: @Alina what do you mean by hang, give specific values.

Comment: from what I know a connection hanging could mean a lot of things (have many causes): processes enter a deadlock or wait to much for a resource (data/CPU/RAM), the network is down, the maximum number of locks for a database was reached... it doesn't really meter what caused the connection to hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a connection actually "hangs", it's often a deadlock. The database is the best place to diagnose and log these problems in detail.

However, I know that the MS SQL Server driver will throw a pretty specific exception after a deadlock victim is chosen and from my (much more limited) experience with Java, I imagine the Sybase driver does the same. You could trap that exception from your application. Even if it's a general exception, you might examine a stack trace or description and ascertain that it pertained to a lock issue.

[This post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/170929) mentions a `LockAcquisitionException` with Java/Sybase.

Comment: This is a good idea and it would solve most of my problem I believe (as hangs can appear, from what I know, because of other reasons too - if someone can correct me, please do so). LockAcquisitionException is actually a Hibernate exception and we are not using Hibernate or any ORM to connect to the database, just JDBC and Spring JDBC Abstraction framework. However I could trap a deadlock execption in my application based on the code of the SQLException. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another "hang" possibility might be a non-optimized database.